# Limit the number of selected item in dropdown list

Tags: dropdown

I have created a list for the scheduling. Users will register but each schedule is limited to only 3 teams. The schedule is a dropdown column.

I need to limit each schedule to only 3 teams and when reached, it will have a text beside it that it is "closed" or disable the item so users will not be able to schedule for that time since it already reached the maximum number of teams.

Example of schedule:

Monday 8am to 9am
Tuesday 1pm to 2pm
Wednesday 5pm to 6pm

If there are 3 users scheduled monday then that dropdown item will have a text "closed" or disable it.

Is this possible to have a code in the column validation inside "formula"?

Hope you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Calculations can be applied only on the same row. In your case it require looking across multiple rows of data.

You can do this by

1. Event Receiver
2. Workflow
3. JavaScript & JSOM
4. JavaScript & SPServices
5. CSR in case of SP2013